# Bootstrap - why minimum media query 768px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, device-width

My phone (LG G2) has a viewport size of 360px 598px.
Col-xs aims devices smaller than 768px, so that means that wether the user is in portrait or landscape mode, he will have the same result, even though in landscape mode i could display more elements due to its larger width. That's why i wonder why the smallest media query is 768px in bootstrap, which doesn't take into account phone's portrait/landscape view.

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: I thought the minimum was 480px: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

Comment: no, not by default, look under "Media queries" : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Then a customised version is for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the LG G2 "could" display more information in landscape, thats not what resposive webdesign intended.

Bootstrap (and others respectively) did choose those breakpoints to create widespread groups of screen sizes/devices. 
They decided to use the iPads width in portrait (768px) as their breakpoint between typical phones and tablets, which makes perfectly sense regarding the amount of work to do. Responsive webdesign is all about creating those groups of devices, to not have to code hundreds of versions for thousends of device types, and still be able to create an optimised view for most devices.

Of course you can still use customised versions, but the more viewport groups you create, the more adjusting and testing will be necessary (and soon enough you're back to useragent sniffing times)

Comment: I'm sorry that I still didn't accept your answer, but you say that responsive webdesign is not intended to do that. But most phones allow viewing in landscape mode, it's not specific to the LG2 in this example. That's why i thought it makes as much sense as a breakpoint for an iPad.
Now maybe it has been considered that the users generally browse websites in portrait mode, and not landscape, and thus not worth the effort of maintaining yet another breakpoint. That argument would make more sense but that's not what you tried to say I think.